# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to install Apache Airflow on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
pip install apache-airflow
Collecting apache-airflow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/2a/6e9efcd40193850e2f636c7306eede2ff5607aa9f81ff9f7a151d9b13ff8/apache-airflow-1.10.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-9gm_exy0/apache-airflow/setup.py", line 124
        async = [
              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why do I get a `SyntaxError`?

After that, I got:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-9gm_exy0/apache-airflow/
```

It seems that I am missing some packages, but I do not know which one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in apache-airflow caused by `async` becoming a reserved keyword in Python 3.7, rendering the package unusable in that version.  [According to the project's bug tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2716), the bug has been fixed in versions 2.0.0 and 1.10.1 of the project, but those have not been released yet at time of writing.  Your only options are (a) use a different Python version, (b) fork the project yourself, or (c) yell at the project's maintainers.